# GoogleMaps Javascript API not displaying KML

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3, kml

I'm trying to get a KML displayed on my site with GoogleMaps Javascript API. The kml is hosted at: https://sites.google.com/a/consultwilliams.com/kml/files

The code I'm using displays the map but, doesn't retrieve the KML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>KML Layers</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

     function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 6,
          center: {lat: 41.876, lng: -87.624}
        });

        var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
          url:'https://sites.google.com/a/consultwilliams.com/kml/files/MILWAUKEE.KML',
          map: map
        });
      }

    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyChJk7GigtgPqgEuKI2Ps7O9ApfTr9PROc&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The status returned by KmlLayer is `DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL of the file is not correct.  The status returned by KmlLayer is `DOCUMENT_NOT_FOUND`.  This works for me:

```
https://sites.google.com/a/consultwilliams.com/kml/files/Milwaukee.kml?attredirects=0&d=1'
```

**code snippet:**

```js
function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 6,
    center: {
      lat: 41.876,
      lng: -87.624
    }
  });

  var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    // url:'https://sites.google.com/a/consultwilliams.com/kml/files/MILWAUKEE.KML',
    url: 'https://sites.google.com/a/consultwilliams.com/kml/files/Milwaukee.kml?attredirects=0&d=1',
    map: map
  });
  google.maps.event.addListener(ctaLayer, 'status_changed', function() {
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = ctaLayer.getStatus();
  })
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initMap);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="status"></div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: That worked! I see now that I didn't have the url set to download! Thanks so much!